# Cannot assign to non-existent property in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

this is my PageThree.qml file

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
Rectangle {

    property alias songModel: song_list_view.model;
    property alias playlistSongs: music_player.playlist

Audio {
            id: music_player;
            autoPlay: false;


        }

}
```

When i try to use the PageThree.qml file in my core.qml file like this

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtMultimedia 5.9
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import "qrc:/stack_pages/"
import "qrc:/images/"

Window {
        PageThree {

            songModel: manager.getSongListByAlbumName(globalName)
            playlistSongs.addItems:
                manager.getSongUrl(globalName)



        }
}
```

i get this following error, `Cannot assign to non-existent property "addItems"`. Although i can set my PageThree songModel i cant assign the value to playlist via add items. the method manager.getSongUrl(globalName) returns `QList<Qurl>`, i need to assign this to play list, even though i can access it i cant set the playlist items via add items, how to resolve this error?Why i cant access the playlist property of the PageThree ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `addItems` is not a property but a method [See Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtmultimedia-playlist.html#addItem-method)

You can assign on completion:

```
PageThree {

    Component.onCompleted: addItems(manager.getSongUrl(globalName))
}
```

Or maybe you have a signal to tell that the list changed and assign on that signal.

**Pro-tip:** If you fiddle a bit it might also be possible to directly assign the list of the manager to the playlist itself, but I'm not sure about all the types involved